# Calculation with Nested loops in R

Tags: r, nested-loops

I have a Geocode dataset with three columns: Latitude, Longitude and Cluster. I calculated the average center of the clusters and store the results in two lists Center_lat and Center_lon.

Now I wanna calculate the distance from each observation(3000+) to each cluster center(30) with the Haversine formula. To get a 3000 by 30 matrix.

I tried to use a nested for loop, but I got the same distance for all clusters. Here's the code.

```
for (i in 1:n){
    for (k in 1:c){
    lat1=radians(Geocode[i,1])
    lon1=radians(Geocode[i,2])
    lat2=radians(Center_lat[k,2])
    lon2=radians(Center_lon[k,2])
    }
    R <- 3958.756 # Earth mean radius [miles]
    dist_mat[i,] <- acos(sin(lat1)*sin(lat2) + cos(lat1)*cos(lat2) * cos(lon2-lon1)) * R
  }
```

I'm also thinking using a lapply to substitute the nested loop. But I'm not sure how to use the function... Any help is appreciated.

```
# Convert to radian
radians = function(theta=0){return(theta * pi / 180)}

# Calculates the geodesic distance from each property to the center of it's current cluster using the
# Spherical Law of Cosines (slc)
get_dist <- function(lat1, lon1, lat2, lon2) {
  R <- 3958.756 # Earth mean radius [miles]
  d <- acos(sin(radians(lat1))*sin(radians(lat2)) + 
              cos(radians(lat1))*cos(radians(lat2)) * cos(radians(lon2)-radians(lon1))) * R
  return(d) # Distance in miles
}

dist_mat<-lapply()
```

Comment: can you add `dput(head(Geocode))` to your question

Comment: Please make your problem **[reproducible](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28481250/2725969)** in the future.  Notice how I did so in my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the type of computation you want to vectorize in R.  Here we use `outer` to generate all the possible combinations of row indices from your `Geocode` data and `Center_x` data, and then apply the distance function in one fell swoop.

First, get data in easier to use form (one matrix for locations, another for centers, first column lats, second lons):

```
# See Data section below for actual data used

# G <- radians(Geocode)
# C <- radians(cbind(Center_lat[, 2], Center_lon[, 2]))    
R <- 3958.756 # Earth mean radius [miles]
```

Define the function, notice how we use the indices to look up the actual coordinates in `G` and `C`, and how the function is vectorized (i.e. we only need to call it once with all the data):

```
my_dist <- function(xind, yind)
  acos(
    sin(G[xind, 1]) * sin(C[yind, 1]) + 
    cos(G[xind, 1]) * cos(C[yind, 1]) * cos(C[yind, 2] - G[xind, 2])
  ) * R
```

And apply it with `outer`:

```
DISTS <- outer(seq.int(nrow(G)), seq.int(nrow(C)), my_dist)

str(DISTS)
# num [1:3000, 1:30] 4208 6500 8623 7303 3864 ...

quantile(DISTS) # to make sure stuff is reasonable:
#     0%       25%       50%       75%      100% 
#  0.000  4107.574  6204.799  8333.155 12422.059
```

This runs in about 30ms on my system.

---

Data:

```
set.seed(1)
lats <- runif(10000, -60, 60) * pi / 180
lons <- runif(10000, -179, 180) * pi / 180

G.ind <- sample(10000, 3000)
C.ind <- sample(10000, 30)

G <- cbind(lats[G.ind], lons[G.ind])
C <- cbind(lats[C.ind], lons[C.ind])
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the illustration!

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you want to write to the matrix once per row and per column, so you'd want to change the matrix within both for loops, like this:

```
for (i in 1:n){
    for (k in 1:c){
        lat1=radians(Geocode[i,1])
        lon1=radians(Geocode[i,2])
        lat2=radians(Center_lat[k,2])
        lon2=radians(Center_lon[k,2])
        R <- 3958.756 # Earth mean radius [miles]
        dist_mat[i,k] <- acos(sin(lat1)*sin(lat2) + cos(lat1)*cos(lat2) * cos(lon2-lon1)) * R
    }
}
```

Comment: oh, right! yeah, I should've realized that. Thanks a lot for pointing it out!